# ListView background image crop

Tags: android, image, listview, background, crop

I have my ListView with image background (it's actually a fragment) but still i have set the background with: `getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table);` I noticed that every time this list shows up bacground image is allways like "fill_parent" also i noticed that listview is fill_parent too but i can fix that with `getListView().setPadding()` but i cant crop background image. Is there any other way to do it? I need background view with aditional buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Method setPadding is just affecting the content of the ListView, but not it's container e.g. the Background. So basically the padding produces unused space inside the ListView. If you want to restrict the ListView you can use the margin attribute:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```

Another and in my opinion better way to hava a ListView with a Button below is:
Use a LinearLayout with orientation vertical. Add the ListView and the Button to this layout.
The ListViews height is `fill_parent` and the Button's `wrap_content`. Now add to both the layout_weight with value 0 for the Button and 1 for the ListView. The result is that the Button is drawn at the bottom of your screen and the ListView just can expand to the rest of the screen (also its background).